# ValueError: A required field in the configuration data was not found. The required fields are: ('developer_token',) Google Ads API

Tags: python, google-ads-api

I'm trying to run the keyword stats report (file found here: https://github.com/googleads/google-ads-python/blob/master/examples/reporting/get_keyword_stats.py) via the Google Ads API. I have the googleads.yaml file setup already. But when I run the report, I'm getting an error that says:

```
ValueError: A required field in the configuration data was not found. The required fields are: ('developer_token',)
```

I have all the required fields in my googleads.yaml file. Please see screenshot below for reference. What could have gone wrong in my code? Why is it not reading the 'developer_token' I have in the googleads.yaml file?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Got the answer here. I was using the old googleads.yaml file. The new YAML config format can be found here: https://github.com/googleads/google-ads-python/blob/master/google-ads.yaml

Answer (score 0):

The documentation of python's client library for the google ads API is not updated, now. The google-ads.yaml file should include values as in the picture:
[image]

Comment: Please don’t paste screenshots of code. Instead, paste code (or, in this case, YAML) as text, and format it using Markdown.